# How to check if one list contains substring in another list?

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file like the one below. And I have a list of zipcodes, I am trying to return the addresses in the JSON file which contain any of the substrings in the list.

```
{"locations":[
    {"location_id": "1",
     "ref": "123 street apt 5N, New York, 10001, USA"
    },
    {"location_id": "2",
     "ref": "124 street apt 6B, New York, 10002, USA"
    },
    {"location_id": "3",
     "ref": "125 street apt 2A, New York, 10002, USA"
    },
    {"location_id": "4",
     "ref": "303 broad ave, New York, 10005, USA"
    }
  ]
}
```

list file:

```
zipcode_list = [10002, 10003, 10004, 10005]
```

Expected return:

```
{"locations":[
    {"location_id": "2",
     "ref": "124 street apt 6B, New York, 10002, USA"
    },
    {"location_id": "3",
     "ref": "125 street apt 2A, New York, 10002, USA"
    },
    {"location_id": "4",
     "ref": "303 broad ave, New York, 10005, USA"
    }
  ]
}
```

Code I have tried, but returns: 'in ' requires string as left operand, not list:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/C/Desktop/zipcode_list.csv')
zipcode_list = df.values.tolist()

with open('C:/Users/C/Downloads/NY.json', 'r+', errors = "ignore") as myData:
    myData = json.load(myData)
    myData_new = [x for x in myData['locations'] if any(xs in x['ref'] for xs in zipcode_list) ]
    myData_new = {'locations':myData_new}
print(myData_new)
```

I am trying to check the substring based on the loop, as the original JSON file and zip code list are huge. How can I make the code work?

Comment: The items in `zipcode_list` are integers, so `xs in x['ref']` will never be true.  Try `str(xs) in x['ref']` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Now there's no errors, but it returns a blank list.

Comment: It works fine for me with the change, I get location_ids 2,3 and 4 in the output...

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: maybe frist write it as normal `for`-loop and you will have place for `print()` to see what you really have in variables. And later convert it to list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this:

first create a function that checks if any of the zipcodes is in the address:

```
def contains(my_string):
    for zip_code in zip_list:
        if str(zip_code) in my_string:
            return True
```

then do the list comprehension using the contains function:

```
my_data_new = [x for x in myData["locations"] if contains(x["ref"])]
```

Comment: Thank you! I changed the "return True" to "return my_string" and it works!